# Create a Widget with the function of auto populate commas or dots into float field (Odoo 13)

Tags: javascript, string, widget, autofill, odoo-13

I'm trying to create a Widget with the function of auto populate commas or dots when the user enters values into the float field by js.

If the user enters 123456789 , it should automatically become 12,345,667.89 immediately.

But In my code, it just works after click a Button:

```
odoo.define('autofill.separate', function (require) {
"use strict";

var basic_fields = require('web.basic_fields');
var registry = require('web.field_registry');

var BoldWidget = basic_fields.FieldChar.extend({
    _renderReadonly: function () {
        this._super();
        var old_html_render = this.$el.html();
        var new_html_render = old_html_render.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")

        
        this.$el.html(new_html_render);
    },
});

registry.add('autofill_separate', BoldWidget);
});
```

Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery mask plugin:

1. add this to your backend assets
   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.min.js
2. update your widget:

   ```
    var basic_fields = require('web.basic_fields');
    var registry = require('web.field_registry');

    var BoldWidget = basic_fields.FieldMonetary.extend({

        _prepareInput: function ($input) {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            this.$input.mask("#,##0.00", {reverse: true});
            return this.$input;
        },

    });
    registry.add('autofill_separate', BoldWidget);
   ```